# Rendering form to bitmap

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, bitmap

I would like to render Form to bitmap...  Is it possible in .net 2.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, you can call `Control.DrawToBitmap()` to render a control to a bitmap.  For more general drawing, you can create a `Bitmap` and then use `Graphics.FromImage()` to create a `Graphics` instance.  You can then draw to this graphics instance as normal.

Here's a simple form that can draw itself (just add a button and double click it to add the Click event handler:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
        b.Save("Test.bmp");
    }
}
```