# Saving image in paint app c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a simple paint app. I got everything working except save. I am doing all the paint operations inside a panel. I need to save it as an image. How to do this?

Comment: Are you using winforms or wpf?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this code

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);//to create bmp of same size as panel
Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(0,0,panel1.Width,panel1.Height); //to set bounds to image
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp,rect);      // drawing panel1 imgae into bmp of bounds of rect
bmp.Save("C:\\a.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); //save location and type
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great example of paint app:
1) [WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DrawTools.aspx)
2) [WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/drawtools.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public void SaveAs()
    {
        SaveFileDialog diag = new SaveFileDialog();
        DialogResult dr = diag.ShowDialog();

        if (dr.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {

            string _filename = diag.FileName;

            // filename not specified. Use FileName = ...
            if (_filename == null || _filename.Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("Unspecified file name");

            // cannot override RO file
            if (File.Exists(_filename)
                && (File.GetAttributes(_filename)
                & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) != 0)
                throw new Exception("File exists and is read-only!");

            // check supported image formats
            ImageFormat format = FormatFromExtension(_filename);
            if (format == null)
                throw new Exception("Unsupported image format");

            // JPG images get special treatement
            if (format.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg))
            {
                EncoderParameters oParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                oParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                ImageCodecInfo oCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
                yourImage.Save(_filename, oCodecInfo, oParams);
            }
            else
                yourImage.Save(_filename, format);

        }
    }
```

Comment: where exactly is it reading the data from panel? I am doing all image related operations on a panel,

Answer (score 1):

If you're using wpf you can take alook at [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx). It can render any visual into a bitmap that you can then save using @danyogiaxs awnser

-edit-

I also found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784295/rendering-form-to-bitmap)
for doing the same on winforms