# Dissolve WinForm into another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm attempting to get my winForms to dissolve into each other, like [Manhole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyOTq1EpV5o).  All of the forms open in the center of the screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is how I open and close forms currently:

```
private void storyChooser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (userChoice)
    {
        case Choice.Son:
            this.Close();
            form2.Show();
            form2.label1.Text = "Son has been choosen.";
            break;
        case Choice.Dad:
            this.Close();
            form2.Show();
            form2.label1.Text = "Dad has been choosen.";
            break;
        case Choice.Mom:
            this.Close();
            form2.Show();
            form2.label1.Text = "Mom has been Choosen.";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

To stop the application from closing down I have all the forms running, but not shown, from the start.  I couldn't get the more memory efficient way to work, so I'm using this as a work around for now.

Comment: You can achieve the effect by making your own form class that shows a borderless form and draws a custom border instead. Upon "fade" you'd animate reduction in the opacity of the form's custom border and when the animation is complete you'd transfer the child elements over to the target form and close the faded form.
  This is a weird way of doing it and a complete hack, it may be easier and more consistent to switch to WPF and define user controls , they'd be easy to fade in and out

Comment: Have a look at: https://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/   Sliding and fading transitions which are easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a cross-fade.  You take an image and interpolate each of the pixels from one image to the other.

This is straight forward to do.  Let's assume that time goes from 0 (all first image) to 1.0 (all last image), then you're going to do something like this:

```
public Color Lerp(Color c1, Color c2, float t)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(Lerp(c1.R, c2.R, t), Lerp(c1.G, c2.G, t), Lerp(c1.B, c2.B, t));
}

public int Lerp(int a, int b, float t)
{
    float tp = 1.0f - t;
    return (int)(tp * a + t * b);
}
```

Your process will be:

1. [Render form1 to a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784295/rendering-form-to-bitmap)
2. Render form2 to a bitmap
3. Allocate a scratch bitmap
4. For t from 0 to 1, stepping by, say .1, Lerp every (x, y) between form1 bitmap and form2 bitmap and set that pixel in the scratch
5. Display the scratch

Now, you can write this code and you should to make sure it works.  If the performance is good enough, let it be.

I don't think you don't actually want to use this code (I write image processing code for a living).  The overhead of doing all the pixel munging in .NET is probably going to bog you down.  You're probably better off getting the raw byte bytes from the bitmaps and doing the lerp on them instead of doing get/get/set pixel.  Further, those three floating point operations per color component are also going to drag you doing, so if it were me, I would do the work in fixed point if I were operating on bytes.

Answer (score 0):

First: WinForms isn't the best choice to create games.

But if you want to or have to you should probably not use multiple forms for this task.

You could create multiple panels in one form and then manipulate their opacity with a timer.

If you create a big game you'll have to create the screens dynamically.

**Sample**

Here's an example how you can create controls dynamically. You could start to create your own controls for different scenarios (like a control that offers n combo boxes for different answers to a question). Then you could start to define your story with steps and each step would then create the right controls, like a 'decision step' that asks a question and selects the next step depending on the answer.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newButton = new Button { Text = "Click me", Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        newButton.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
    }

    void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I was clicked");
        var button = sender as Button;
        button.Click -= new EventHandler(newButton_Click);
        this.panel1.Controls.Remove(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of creating controls in panes based off of conditions?  For instance having buttons and radiobuttons change depending on where the story is at.