# Overlaying an image in WPF over a Winforms control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to be able to overlay an image, which should be movable and sizeable within the panel it belongs, and is in WPF, over the top of a WinForms control.
I have already quite easily achieve the moveable/sizeable at runtime image, in WPF. I also decided to import the WinForms control into the WPF control to try and do the overlay, however, it just appears to show the WinForms control only, with no image overlayed on top (with 50% opacity). 
The rest of the system I am working with is WinForms, and the WinForms control I am trying to overlay is quite a large control and I'd rather not have to convert it to WPF to achieve this task.
Anyone got any hints on the best way to go about doing this? Basically the image itself is relevant to the control, and the user will be aligning parts of the image (hence resize and move) with parts of the control.
Thanks for you time

Comment: I have tried having the Winforms control on a panel, behind the ElementHost control hosting the WPF image to be overlayed. This ONLY shows the WPF control, and not the Winforms control.

Comment: I have then tried the more convoluted method of loading the Winforms control into the WPF usercontrol, and trying to overlay the image this way, but doing this, the Winforms control is essentially always on top and I can no longer see the image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to render your (hidden) WPF element to an image, and use GDI to draw the image on top of your windows forms content.

Comment: Not sure if I need further elaboration on this explanation. My image in the WPF control need interaction, it still needs to behave as a control. I need to be able to move and resize the image within the canvas, perhaps even rotate and warp the image in the future. It needs to have a degree of opacity so I can move it for alignment purposes over a target control that's a Winforms control. I'm not sure I can do this with what you describe. The simplest solution is just finding out why I can't make the ElementHost completely transparent, or the canvas on the WPF control transparent to Winforms

Comment: The issue with windows forms is that the is no transparency supported between any controls. This is why your are struggling. My only other suggestion is to capture the input on the overlay image and forward it to the hidden wpf elements. Perhaps a totally separate wpf window (to host your wpf overlay content) hovering over your winforms control would work best. The only problem faced would be synchronizing the position and I think that would be trivial. Consider an invisible window to get your started -> http://jonsblogat.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/wpf-invisible-window.html

Comment: Ok, what if I just want to render my Winforms control manually on the WPF control, how would I best go about doing this? Basically how do I pass some kind of Graphics context from the WPF control down to be rendered by the Winforms, and let the WPF control continue as normal?

Comment: You can render a control to bitmap (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784295/rendering-form-to-bitmap) and pass the bitmap to WPF

Answer (score 0):

In the end, to do this, I used a suggestion similar to what was mentioned by Gusdor. Rather than use the DrawToBitmap function, I rendered what I wanted to see from the control to a metafile, and then rendered the metafile in the WPF control. This all worked well and solved this unusual problem. Thanks to all that helped

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you will need to [host windows forms content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx) inside a WPF usercontrol (with the overlayed image) that is hosted inside an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control.

Comment: Does this work?, I always thought GDI was rendered on top of WPF when using WindowsFormsHost, I could be wrong so don't hold me to that ;)

Comment: I've tried to do this and it doesn't work. It only displays the WinForms control and I no longer see the WPF control

Comment: If I have known that you had already tried this, I would not have suggested it as an answer.