# Printing a windows form with tree view structure (scrollbar) and some other controls

Tags: .net, winforms, printing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKh4j.jpg)

I have attached my form in that there are 2 group box 1 on top and another on bottom, and there is a tree view. I need to print this form. I tried few solutions but I don't have proper answer.

1. I tried to capture the screen and save it as .oxps file in this my form not fit to the default a4 size and what is visible in that form only it was saved
2. I tried another method by auto scroll and capture continues screen shot and saving but in that each and every screenshot top and bottom group box was saved

Any one give a solution in c# that it should print tree structure  fully and top/bottom group box only once

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bitmaps to capture the forms using the Control.DrawToBitmap() method (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784295/rendering-form-to-bitmap)).

To only capture the TreeView you could do:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(yourTreeView.Width, yourTreeView.Height);
yourTreeView.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, yourTreeView.Width, yourTreeView.Height));
```